# How control re-position depends on other control visibility in same panel

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have two buttons inside a stack panel. Initially B1 button is on top, then B2. I will change button visibility dynamically from code so that, when I change B1 visibility hidden, then B2 will come on top. How can I achieve this functionality.

```
    <Grid>
      <StackPanel >
        <Button Content="B1" Height="20" Width="100" Visibility="Visible"/>
        <Button Content="B2" Height="20" Width="100" Visibility="Visible"/>
     </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: What you mean by "Top" you mean one above another?

Comment: Yes. Top means one above another.

Comment: remove `StackPanel` and put `B1` after `B2`

Comment: @Bolu is right, and I misinterpreted the question, first thought was the OP meant stack order, not z-index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you remove the Statckpanel and put then in a Grid and you can achieve 
Try something like this.

```
        <Grid>
            <Button Content="B1" Height="20" Width="100" Visibility="Visible" Click="Button_Click" x:Name="B1" />
            <Button Content="B2" Height="20" Width="100" Visibility="Visible" x:Name="B2" Click="B2_Click" />
        </Grid>


    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        B1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
        B2.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    }

    private void B2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        B2.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
        B1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

This should give you similar behaviour. Change according to your use