# re-position control depends on other control's visibility

Tags: wpf, xaml

Actually the following answer does not solve my purpose. Hence raising another question.
[How control re-position depends on other control visibility in same panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28881444/how-control-re-position-depends-on-other-control-visibility-in-same-panel/28881783#28881783).
I have two buttons inside a stack panel. Initially B1 button is on top, then B2.

```
    <Grid>
     <StackPanel >
      <Button Content="B1" Height="20" Width="100" Visibility="Visible"/>
      <Button Content="B2" Height="20" Width="100" Visibility="Visible"/>
     </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

So, using this XAML, when I open application, I can see both B1 and B2 button in UI. 
Now, pragmatically, if I do B1's visibility Hidden, then B2 will take the position of B1 button, and again if I do B1's visibility "Visible", then in the UI, B1 & B2 both will be shown. How to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using Visibility.Collapsed of the button.

```
<StackPanel>
        <StackPanel >
            <Button Content="B1" Height="20" Width="100" Visibility="Visible" x:Name="B1"/>
            <Button Content="B2" Height="20" Width="100" Visibility="Visible" x:Name="B2"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Content="Collapse B1" Click="Button_Click"/>
            <Button Content="Collapse B2" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
            <Button Content="Visible Both" Click="Button_Click_2"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();   

    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        B1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        B2.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        B1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        B2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```